# Generate new variable in R by for loop index

Tags: r, for-loop

Hello and thanks in advance.  I have a simple for loop, but the tricky part is that for every i in the counter, I'd like to generate a new variable that's indexed by i:

```
for (i in c(1,2,3)) {
    var_[i] <- i + 2
}
```

So the end result I'm trying to get is three variables var_1, var_2, var_3 equal to 3,4 and 5 respectively.

Comment: You'll need to look at `assign`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stick with your `for` loop and create many objects in your environment, you can just use `assign`:

```
ls()
# character(0)

for (i in c(1,2,3)) {
  assign(paste0("var_", i), i + 2)
}

ls()
# [1] "i"     "var_1" "var_2" "var_3"
var_1
# [1] 3
var_2
# [1] 4
var_3
# [1] 5
```

(There may be a better way to do whatever it is you're trying to do though...)

Comment: Thanks!  That seems to have done it! Do you know how I can easily put all those new points into a dataframe?